# How to curl pdf pages in android

Tags: android, pdf, page-curl

I search lot more but don't get the proper code to implement in my project,I want to curl each pages of PDF file ,like normal book but not able to do,In my code when I click  on button PDF file load from sdCard.

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/android.pdf");
if (file.exists()) {
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try {
     startActivity(intent);
      } 
      catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
       "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl grabs the full web page/file. you'll need to split the PDF into individual pages after grabbing or use a 3rd party tool or website and then grab the single page it produces

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/
probably something simular to : http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13371